# MySQL: How do I find out which tables reference a specific table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I want to drop a table but it is referenced by one or more other tables. How can I find out which tables are referencing this table without having to look at each of the tables in the database one by one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/806989 has more votes than this question... Though this was asked and answered before that.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema_name'
      AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name';
```

This works.

Comment: For newbies - "TABLE_SCHEMA" is basically your Database name.

Answer (score 12):

```
select table_name 
from information_schema.referential_constraints 
where referenced_table_name = 'parent table here';
```

Comment: The table referential_constraints does not exist in information_schema. I was looking in this database for an answer but can't find it.
MySQL version is 5.0.51a-24-log (Debian)

Answer (score 2):

If you have [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) installed, you can use its [designer feature](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/relations.html#designer) to visualize table relationships.

[image]

To use the designer, select a database, then look for the **Designer** tab.

Answer (score 0):

you could try MySql workbench which allows you to extract E.R. diagram. In this you can find all you need about tables of your database.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want the specific column where the references are made use the following query.

```
SELECT 
ku.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS "Foreign key",
CONCAT("`", ku.TABLE_SCHEMA, "`.`", ku.TABLE_NAME, "`") AS "In",
GROUP_CONCAT(ku.COLUMN_NAME) AS "Source column",
CONCAT("`", ku.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA, "`.`", ku.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, "`") AS 
"References",
GROUP_CONCAT(ku.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME) AS "Target column"
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS ku
WHERE ku.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = '[THE_CURRENT_SELECTED_SCHEMA_NAME]'
AND ku.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = '[THE_CURRENT_SELECTED_TABLE_NAME]'
GROUP BY ku.CONSTRAINT_NAME
HAVING `In` != `References`
```

[image]

Comment: this is too long as a solution.

Comment: Maybe add a simplification, I'll vote up then.

Comment: @BelkacemThiziri, I have added an image to clearly show what this query will display, the query might look long but the end result is beautiful.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use Toad to load it up and you can view the references through the diagram. also make sure that you don't have any app code passing sql from the front-end, dropping the table may cause the app to break.

Download link
http://www.toadsoft.com/toadmysql/FreewareDownload.htm

If you are using innoDB try this one SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM yourdatabasename LIKE 'T' http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html

Comment: If you are using innoDB try this one

SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM yourdatabasename LIKE 'T' 

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html

Answer (score -1):

Look at the KEY_COLUMN_USAGE table in the iformation_schema schema.

Answer (score -1):

from the mysql command line:
show table status