# How to find all tables that have foreign keys that reference particular table.column and have values for those foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table whose primary key is referenced in several other tables as a foreign key.  For example:

```
  CREATE TABLE `X` (
    `X_id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`X_id`)
  )
  CREATE TABLE `Y` (
    `Y_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `X_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`Y_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `Y_X` FOREIGN KEY (`X_id`) REFERENCES `X` (`X_id`)
  )
  CREATE TABLE `Z` (
    `Z_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `X_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`Z_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `Z_X` FOREIGN KEY (`X_id`) REFERENCES `X` (`X_id`)
  )
```

Now, I don't know how many tables there are in the database that contain foreign keys into X like tables Y and Z. Is there a SQL query that I can use to return:

1. A list of tables that have foreign keys into X
2. AND which of those tables actually have values in the foreign key

Answer (score 421):

Here you go:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'X'
  AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'X_id';
```

If you have multiple databases with similar tables/column names you may also wish to limit your query to a particular database:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'X'
  AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'X_id'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';
```

Comment: SELECT TABLE_NAME more better then SELECT *

Comment: For what kind of DB is this useful? MySql?

Comment: @Cirelli94 The question is tagged as a MySQL question.

Answer (score 65):

MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual: ["InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

```
SELECT
  ke.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA parentSchema,
  ke.referenced_table_name parentTable,
  ke.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME parentColumnName,
  ke.TABLE_SCHEMA ChildSchema,
  ke.table_name childTable,
  ke.COLUMN_NAME ChildColumnName
FROM
  information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ke
WHERE
  ke.referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL
  AND ke.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'ci_id' ## Find Foreign Keys linked to this Primary Key
ORDER BY
  ke.referenced_table_name;
```

Answer (score 26):

This solution will not only display all relations but also the constraint name, which is required in some cases (e.g. drop constraint):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(table_name, '.', column_name) AS 'foreign key',
    CONCAT(referenced_table_name, '.', referenced_column_name) AS 'references',
    constraint_name AS 'constraint name'
FROM
    information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE
    referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL;
```

If you want to check tables in a specific database, add the following:

```
AND table_schema = 'database_name';
```

Answer (score 16):

You can find all schema related information in the wisely named `information_schema` table.

You might want to check the table `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` and `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`. The former tells you which tables are referenced by others; the latter will tell you how their fields are related.

Answer (score 6):

Listing all foreign keys in a db including description

```
    SELECT  
    i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME, i1.TABLE_NAME,i1.COLUMN_NAME,
    i1.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA,i1.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, i1.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,
    i2.UPDATE_RULE, i2.DELETE_RULE 
    FROM   
    information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS i1  
    INNER JOIN 
    information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS i2 
    ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    WHERE i1.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL  
    AND  i1.TABLE_SCHEMA  ='db_name';
```

restricting to a specific column in a table table

```
AND i1.table_name = 'target_tb_name' AND i1.column_name = 'target_col_name'
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a little *bash onliner* that you can write to a script to get a friendly output:

mysql_references_to:

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASS -A DB_NAME -se "USE information_schema; SELECT * FROM KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = '$1' AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'id'\G" | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' |egrep "\<TABLE_NAME|\<COLUMN_NAME" |sed 's/TABLE_NAME: /./g' |sed 's/COLUMN_NAME: //g' | paste -sd "," -| tr '.' '\n' |sed 's/,$//' |sed 's/,/./'
```

So the execution: `mysql_references_to transaccion` (where *transaccion* is a random table name) gives an output like this:

```
carrito_transaccion.transaccion_id
comanda_detalle.transaccion_id
comanda_detalle_devolucion.transaccion_positiva_id
comanda_detalle_devolucion.transaccion_negativa_id
comanda_transaccion.transaccion_id
cuenta_operacion.transaccion_id
...
```

Answer (score 3):

## 06 2022

Based on @Panayotis answer but with better structure.

This will list out all the constrains from multiple tables.
I have included the `TABLE_SCHEMA` to show the database name too.

### SQL

```sql
SELECT
    TABLE_SCHEMA AS 'Database',
    TABLE_NAME AS t1,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME AS 't2 (reference table)',
    COLUMN_NAME AS 't1 column',
    REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME AS 't2 column (reference table)',
    CONSTRAINT_NAME AS 't1 (constrain name)'
FROM
    information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE
    referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL
```

### Output

```
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
| Database   | t1         | t2 (reference table) | t1 column     | t2 column (reference table) | t1 (constrain name)    |
+============+============+=====================+===============+============================+========================+
| foobar     | credential | userdetail          | userdetail_fk | id                         | credentialUserdetailFk |
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
| foobar     | loginlog   | userdetail          | userdetail_fk | id                         | loginlogUserdetailFk   |
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
+ client     | userdetail | client              | client_fk     | id                         | userdetailClientFk     |
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE `CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA` LIKE 'your_database'
AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` LIKE 'your_database'
AND `REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA` LIKE 'your_database'
AND `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'your_table'
AND `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` LIKE 'your_column';

Answer (score -4):

Easiest:
1. Open phpMyAdmin
2. On the left click database name
3. On the top right corner find "Designer" tab

All constraints will be shown there.

Comment: Oh my, I didn't know this option existed! (+1) And it actually shows all the constraints.

Comment: This might be helpful, but if you have a large database, then the diagram will be cluttered.