# Select a list of keys of a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table "products" and I would like to check if this table has any  indexes, foreign keys etc

A "DESCRIBE products" would give some information.

```
Field        Type           Null    Key    Default   Extra
productCode  varchar(200)   NO      MUL    NULL  
description  varchar(500)   NO             NULL
```

Mainly the key field in the case. But defenietly no references and what table is linked to who etc etc.

What is the best way to get such information via SQL about a table?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/mysql-how-to-i-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE products
```

which gives you the query for creating the table. The most informative.

Answer (score 7):

SHOW INDEXES IN `<tablename>` will give all the indexes in that table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about foreign keys, but `SHOW INDEX FROM tablename;` gives a lot of easily parsed information.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as documented here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW FIELDS FROM $DATABASE.$TABLE_NAME");

$i = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['Field'] . ' ' . $row['Type'];
}
```