# Get all tables where a primary key is linked to a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

Can I retrieve all the table names and the associated column names where a primary key is linked to a foreign key in another table?

E.g.: I have a table `EMPLOYEE` and its primary key is linked to by a foreign key in many other tables, say `DEPT`, `ACCOUNT` and so on.

Is there a way that I can can get the table and column names of those tables where I have used employee's Primary key as a Foreign Key?

Comment: lokk at this : 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/mysql-how-to-i-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular

Comment: Did you try to read your question? Why do you type in such a way? It's incredibly DIFFICULT to read. You can query `information_schema.referential_constraints` and obtain the info you need. Look up the docs to see how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the "View Dependencies" feature for the primary-table to get that info, in the SSMS.
Also there some tools available that help you do that, one such in "SQLSpec".
It's a pretty good tool for database documentation.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/sqlspec/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

by chance today i got the same query in my mind and using google i found the following sql

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,
type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
```

you can update the `LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'` as per your need.

i use this in `sqlserver2005`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks A lot Everyone... i Did it in Postgresql Where in i fired the following Query:

```
SELECT constraint_name 
FROM information_schema.referential_constraints 
WHERE unique_constraint_name='table_name_pkey'
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it when the system permits you to do so.