# MySQL: How to find where a specific primary key is used as a foreign key in other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm working on implementing a function to prevent removal of certain elements in a database (through the front end) if they have other items associated with them in other tables. Otherwise those other tables are looking for keys that aren't there.

If you understood that my hat is off to you.

I have *many* sets of tables to look through and need either a SQL query or a MySQL Workbench feature that can tell me, on entry of the primary key (column name, not actual value), if that key is used as a foreign key somewhere else.

Otherwise if anyone knows an offhand workaround, that would be great too!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to I find all tables that have foreign keys that reference particular table.column AND have values for those foreign keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/mysql-how-to-i-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular)

Comment: Why not simply try to delete the item and catch any error that you get from the FK violation?

Comment: See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-constraints-table.html (specific) and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html (in general)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Tried that, but the tables are all very interdependant and I nearly screwed myself up royally. I crashed the app on tablemapping until I could search through and find the foreign key references, but it took a long time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  table_name, column_name     
FROM
  information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE
  referenced_table_name = '<table>'
  and referenced_column_name = '<primary key column>'
```

Comment: key_column_usage doesn't exist?

Comment: That is probably because the username you're connecting with doesn't have the access rights to view the table..

Comment: sorry, meant to update, had to reopen my interface, it was stuck inside the schema (randomly, don't ask!). Anyway, found it and used your code, but am getting the following error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'operatingsystem' in 'where clause'. operating system is a table name and is under referenced-table-name in the query...

Answer (score 0):

A solution is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/mysql-how-to-i-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular) to retrieve this information from information_Schema table.

1) If you want to work on these tables from your code, then fetch them as a container, for example ArrayList in your code and perform your logic.

2) If you want to work on these tables from your Stored Procedure, then use temporary tables to achive the same work you'd do in your java code through containers.

Comment: I am fetching them with Hibernate and putting them into an ArrayList