# How to count amount of rows referring to a foreign key in MySql?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Let's say a table like

```
CREATE TABLE `testdb`.`test` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

there are other tables may have foreign key referring to test.id column. The interesting thing is I don't know what table has such a foreign key and how many rows the table has.

now I want to calculate amount of rows dispersing in tables that have foreign key to test.id. Is it possible?

I think it's theoretically possible, otherwise MySql cannot do operations like `ON DELETE CASCADE`, `DELETE SET NULL` ...

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Other tables have references to that table but not that table to the other refencences.

Comment: I think not knowing that amount is part of the whole idea.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically figure out the foreign key constraints from the other tables?  Do you want to do all your checks within MySQL?  Are you afraid of using regexes?

Comment: there must be a way to find out where are these references, otherwise  ON DELETE CASCADE is impossible. however, mysql may not expose that interface to user.

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez: I am not figuring out what table schema has that foreign key. I am trying to count the amount of rows tables have, where tables has that foreign key at runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to I find all tables that have foreign keys that reference particular table.column AND have values for those foreign keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/mysql-how-to-i-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular)

Comment: @JohnFx, yep the answer in that post will answer the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes it's duplicate. Both topic got perfectly answered!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Displays all referenced tables with row counts**

```
SELECT rc.table_name, t.TABLE_ROWS
FROM `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` rc
INNER JOIN `TABLES` t ON t.TABLE_NAME = rc.TABLE_NAME
WHERE rc.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = "test"
```

**Displays sum of all referenced tables row count**

```
SELECT SUM(t.TABLE_ROWS) AS allReferencedTablesRowCount
FROM `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` rc
INNER JOIN `TABLES` t ON t.TABLE_NAME = rc.TABLE_NAME
WHERE rc.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = "test"
```

Comment: I am using mysql, does above only apply to SQLServer?

Comment: no it applies for mysql but above mysql 5.1 (The REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS table was added in MySQL 5.1.10. The REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME column was added in MySQL 5.1.16.)

Answer (score 0):

if you have foreign-key-constraints defined you can read them from the database schema to see which columns in which tables are linked to your primary key.

edit: [check this](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/mysqlquerytree.php) (on the left side select "Database metadata" -> "Find child tables")

Comment: As @JohnFx mentioned, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/mysql-how-to-i-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular