# Get all Django cascading dependent models of an auth_user

Tags: python, mysql, django, model, cascade-filtering

I would like to get all django models that depend (has foreign key) on a particular `auth_user` (User model)

The SQL version of this would look [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/mysql-how-to-i-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular#answer-1133461) except that example isn't recursive as i would like to.

Ideally i would like to delete any related data to a particular `User` without destroying that User, like triggering the cascade-delete but skipping the deleting of the root object, in this example the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `related_name` of all ForeignKeys or M2M keys to User model, like this:

```
# you models.py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    user = models.ForeignKey(related_name='userrelated__somemodel')

# views.py
# you can get all dependence names of user model attributes
all_user_attrs = dir(request.user)
# ['userrelated__somemodel1', 'userrelated__somemodel2', ...]
# and here you can get all names only related fields
related_fields = filter(lambda x: 'userrelated__' in x, all_user_attrs)
# and if you want to get this field, you can do this:
for attr_name in related_fields:
    attr = getattr(request.user, attr_name, None)
    print attr
```

Comment: This looks good but I cannot change `related_name='userrelated__...` on every model, they are already set to other meaningful values and i would break the app.

Comment: Also, you can get all default user method and attrs, and all methods and attrs from your project. Different is a Fkeys, m2m-keys and o2o keys :]