# Find all foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with an ID, multiple other tables with Foreign key holding that parent ID.

Is there an efficient way to check which tables contain the ID in their FK column, without declaring the child table names? I'm using MySql

Comment: Please clarify - are you trying to get a list of tables that have foreign keys that refer to the "parent" table's ID column, or are you trying to get a list of tables that not only have such a relationship to the parent table but also contain a discrete value for that column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to I find all tables that have foreign keys that reference particular table.column AND have values for those foreign keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/mysql-how-to-i-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular)