# SQL Return list of tables containing foreign keys related to a primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am trying to query the mySQL database to return a list of tables containing a foreign key associated with a primary key. For example, I have a table containing "reference_number" and other tables containing "reference_number" as a foreign key. How would I query the database to return the list of tables containing "reference_number" as a foreign key? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate:

[MySQL: How to I find all tables that have foreign keys that reference particular table.column AND have values for those foreign keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/mysql-how-to-i-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular)

A possible solution is:

```
USE information_schema;
SELECT *
FROM
  KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'
  AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'reference_number';
```