# Adding column to existing unique key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table created in mysql.

```
 CREATE TABLE `postitem` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `createdBy_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `post_category_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_4cscn0qw8u7go5hvmofq0ersg` (`post_category_id`,`item_name`),
  KEY `FK_ncg8dotnqoetaiem6hiokvpwy` (`createdBy_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ncg8dotnqoetaiem6hiokvpwy` FOREIGN KEY (`createdBy_id`) REFEREN                                                                                                                     CES `applicationuser` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_nfh1xw0eqqu9wg5hhl7iqdk56` FOREIGN KEY (`post_category_id`) REF                                                                                                                     ERENCES `postcategory` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=737 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Now I need to add one more column `createdBy_id` to `UNIQUE KEY`. How can I do that?

Comment: createdBy_id  is already a coloumn and you want to have another with same name is this you want?

Comment: I want createdBy_id to be part of unique constraint along with other two columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the existing constraint, and then recreate it with the new fields.
I suggest renaming it to something more appropriate at the same time:

```
ALTER TABLE `postitem` DROP INDEX `UK_4cscn0qw8u7go5hvmofq0ersg`;
ALTER TABLE `postitem` ADD CONSTRAINT `UK_Post_Item_CreatedBy` 
   UNIQUE (`post_category_id`,`item_name`, `createdBy_id`);
```

**Edit: Re Foreign Key Constraints**

Since you are changing the uniqueness of the constraint, all tables which are referencing your `postitem` table via the above UKC will now need to be remodelled to accommodate the new column `createdBy_id` as well. So for each such referencing table, you will need to

- Drop the FOREIGN KEY constraint
- Add the new `createdBy_id` column (same type)

Now you can

- Drop the Unique Key constraint on `postitem`
- Add the new Unique Key constraint on `postitem` with the extra column

And again for each referencing table

- Add a new foreign key constraint referencing `postitem(post_category_id, item_name, createdBy_id))`

However, at this point I would suggest that you rethink your table design here. You have a single primary key `id` on the `postitem` table, which IMO would generally be a better candidate for foreign key constraints to reference. i.e. I would suggest that instead, you:

- DROP the foreign key constraints on referencing tables as above
- DROP the columns `post_category_id` and `item_name` in these tables
- Instead, ADD a new Column `postitemid bigint(20)` to these tables
- Create a new FOREIGN KEY constraint from `otherTable.postitemid` to `postitem(id)`

Obviously, this may now have massive impact on the rest of your system.

One of the main benefits of simple surrogate keys (like `AUTO_INCREMENT INTs`) is that they are more resilient to change, which I guess we've just proven here.

Comment: I tried. But it gave an error: Error Code : 1553
Cannot drop index 'UK_4cscn0qw8u7go5hvmofq0ersg': needed in a foreign key constraint

Comment: you said "Add the new createdBy_id column (same type)". In which table do i need to add?

Comment: @user755806 in all tables referencing this constraint. This [query will help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1133461/314291) - its the `TABLE_NAME` output column is the one you need.

Comment: Thanks much for your answer. But I dont understand why createdBy_id is required in referencing tables?

Comment: You've inherited a bit of a messy design - mostly, you'll want all referencing tables to use a tables primary key on a foreign key constraint. However, in this case, someone has decided to add a foreign key to `postitem(post_category_id, item_name)` which is preventing you from changing the constraint.