# how to know where primary key is passed as foreign key in other tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table named as contacts and an other table as custom_field_values and many more tables where contact_id is passed as FK.
I want to know those tables who have contact_id as FK.

Comment: if foreign key(contact_id) is with the same name in other table, simply take the natural join of tables, submit the query. If you get some data back , these are those tables. 
Not 100% true but will work most of the time

Comment: May have been solved for you here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/mysql-how-to-i-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular#1133461

Comment: @MuhamamdUsman in contacts table it's "id" & and in custom_field_values it's "contacts_id"