# How to find all relation of a user in a SQL database?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to find all tables pointing to a specific user in a SQL database.

Consider table `users` with one column  `id` as primary.

How would I find all tables that have reference to a specific user with the user `id` primary.

Comment: this.. might not be trivial. you will need to [find all other table that referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/754582/4648586) your `users` table. then (possibly using loop) check on all of them for given `id`.